# jQuery: Disable post publish button on condition

Tags: jquery, wordpress, onclick, click, disable

I need to include a validation on the post publish button. I have added a new custom text field in post editor page. If the publish button is clicked and this field is empty, I need to throw an error and do not save this post.

I can catch the click event of the button here.

```
$(".editor-post-publish-button").live('click', function(e){
    console.log("Publish Click");
});
```

But I do not know how to display the error and disable the post saving. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is event.stopImmediatePropagation()
https://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

```
$(".editor-post-publish-button").on('click', function(e){
     //check for validations
     if (!valid) {   
          alert("Validations not met")                 
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();             
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(".editor-post-publish-button").on('click', function(e){
 if (!valid) {                     /// check here if the form is valid
e.preventDefault();                /// e.preventDefault prevent your button submit
}
});
```

As for error you can display a span below  tag or alert("error") or another type dependant on your choice

Comment: e.preventDefault() does not work because the button has been applied a custom event to publish the post. It's not a submit button

Comment: what if you hide the button and create a new button which on click you check for validation and if valid click  from js the hidden button